# Why the eval creates method as private method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

This snippet of code creates method as a private method, why?

```
a = %q{def hello() "Hello there!" end}
class A; end
A.class.send(:eval, a)
A.new.hello #=> NoMethodError: private method `hello' called for A
```

Platform: ruby 1.9.3p125, tested in `pry`

Comment: I don't have this problem in Ruby 1.9.3. It works as you'd expect.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that error. Is `eval` somehow patched to something else?

Comment: I confirm OP's reported behaviour. I noticed that when the method is defined using (public) `class_eval`, it doesn't raise this error, only when you define it using (private) `eval`.

Comment: Somehow the definition of this method goes to Object, then object main has 'hello' method as private method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods which are defined outside of any module (so called *global methods*) are actually defined as private instance methods of `Object`. That way, the can be called everywhere (since everything inherits from `Object`), and they can only be called without an explicit receiver.

This includes methods like `require`, `load`, `puts`, `print`, `p`, `gets`, and `eval`. (Note: most of those are *actually* defined in `Kernel` and mixed into `Object` but the effect and the objective is the same.)

In your case, you *are* defining a method outside of any module: there is no mention of a module in your `a` string. The fact that you are calling `eval` on `A.class` is completely irrelevant. Like I said above: `eval` is a global method defined on `Object` for convenience reasons (so that it may be called everywhere). Your `A.class.send(:eval)` is just a very convoluted way of calling the global private `eval` method. It does not somehow magically set the context of the `eval`uated string to `A.class`.

You could do `42.send(:eval)` instead and the result would still be the same, just like `puts('Hello')` and `42.send(:puts, 'Hello')` are exactly the same, because they end up calling the exact same method.

And by the way: even if it *did*, it still wouldn't do what you want. `A.class` is just `Class` (the `class` of *any* class is *always* `Class`), so if it *did* work as you expect, the method would be defined in `Class`, not in `A`.